# How to continuously read data from socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets

The problem is that i don't know how much bytes i will receive from socket, so i just trying to loop.

```
buffer = ''

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    buffer += data
    print buffer
```

As I understood `recvfrom` return only specified size of bytes and the discards other data, is it possible somehow continuously read this data to buffer variable?

Comment: try using `recv` rather than `recvfrom`

Answer (score 6):

It wont discard the data, it will just return the data in the next iteration. What you are doing in your code is perfectly correct.

The only thing I would change is a clause to break the loop:

```
buffer = ''

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recv(1024)
    if data:
        buffer += data
        print buffer
    else:
        break
```

An empty string signifies the connection has been broken according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

If this code still does not work then it would be good to show us how you are setting up your socket.

Comment: still the same, only first 1024

Comment: also, try using `recv` rather than `recvfrom`

Comment: mmm, yea, sorry, the problem solved with `Exceptions` and `setblocking`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using readline as the buffer and use "\n" as the separator between lines:

```
#read one line from the socket
def buffered_readLine(socket):
    line = ""
    while True:
        part = socket.recv(1)
        if part != "\n":
            line+=part
        elif part == "\n":
            break
    return line
```

This is helpful when you want to buffer without closing the socket.

sock.recv(1024) will hang when there is no data being sent unless you close the socket on the other end.